# Action is receiving previous local State in React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning React Redux since last few days. I have built a small App. I am trying to send data back to API with updated likes for the news Object.

Here is a code for the News Item Component.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { updateArticleLikes } from '../../actions/updateNews';

class NewsItem extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      likes: 0,
      key: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      likes: this.props.item.likes,
      key: this.props.item.key
    })
  }

  increaseCount = event => {
    this.newState(event);
  }

  newState = (event) => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState({
      likes: this.props.item.likes + 1,
      key: this.props.item.key
    }, this.submitUpdate(event))
  }

  submitUpdate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(this.state)

    this.props.updateArticleLikes(this.state)
    this.setState({likes: 0, key: ''})
  }

  render(){
    const {item } = this.props
    return(
      <div key={item.key} >
        <h4> - <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{item.title} </a></h4>
        <button onClick ={ this.increaseCount }  data-likes={item.likes} value={item.key}>Like { this.state.likes }</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    { updateArticleLikes }, dispatch);
};


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NewsItem);
```

And here is code for the updateArticleLikes action.

```
   import { API_URL } from '../global';

    export function updateArticleLikes(data) {
      // here, it shows old state in data
     console.log(data)
      return dispatch => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({"article": data}))
        return fetch(API_URL + '/newsupdate', {
          method: 'PATCH',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({"article": data})
       })
      }
    }
```

The problem is for some reason, function updateArticleLikes is receiving the previous state. I am sure that newState function is updating local state, because I can see it's value in DOM in button tag ({this.state.like}) but I don't understand why action is receiving the previous state.

I thought of mapStateToProps but it will not work in this case as I am dealing with the local state. Can't make it work since past two days! Any suggestion?

**The solution that Worked:**

Oblosys helped me to solve this. After removing the argument from submitUpdate function and also removing seState and preventDefault my function works great now. It is updating and displaying the correct state and also sending right data to the server. Here is my changed code for anyone having the same problem.

```
  newState = (event) => {
    console.log(this.state)
    event.persist()
    this.setState({
      likes: this.props.item.likes + 1,
      key: this.props.item.key
    }, this.submitUpdate)
  }

  submitUpdate = () => {
    this.props.updateArticleLikes(this.state)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `this.submitUpdate(event)` is a parameter of `this.setState`, it gets evaluated before `setState` is even called, instead of when the state is updated. You can prevent this by turning it into a thunk: `() => this.submitUpdate(event)`.

Note that you'll also have to do an `event.persist()` if you want to use the event in the `setState` callback (or, preferably, just handle the `preventDefault` before that and not pass it at all, since calling `preventDefault` on persisted events is a bit dodgy.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Oblosys. I understand your point that submitUpdate is getting evaluated even before setState is called. But I am having a hard time understanding your statement "I can prevent this by turning it into a thunk: () => this.submitUpdate(event)." Would you mind to explain me a little bit about it?

Comment: The callback argument of `setState` should be a function, but you are passing a value (i.e. the result of calling `this.submitUpdate` with argument `event`, being `undefined`) By wrapping the call in an anonymous function with no arguments (the thunk), you will defer its execution until the callback actually gets called (after the state has been updated.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Oblosys, you pushed me in right direction. It sends correct data now. My edited code is up in the question if anyone else is having the same problem.